# simulating gain vs parameter in LTSpice

Tags: integrated-circuit, ltspice, simulation

I tried to dc sweep V3 in my circuit and measure the gain.
But it does not give a correct result.

What I am trying to do is actually recreating some measurements from the datasheet.

Maybe there is a simulation techniques that I do not know yet.
Appreciate any suggestion.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your graphs appear to indicate that it does work.

Comment: @Andyaka As I understand it, it should be like the Fig.3 above. it should be linear-in-dB against vgain.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Datasheet of the AD8337 (Rev. D)](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8337.pdf), page 21/28 under section **Gain control considerations**:

> The offset voltage effect of the AD8337, as with all VGAs, can
> appear as a complex waveform when observed across the range
> of VGAIN voltage. Generated by multiple sources, each device has
> a unique offset voltage (VOS) profile while the GAIN input is
> swept through its voltage range.

At least from what I can understand, you're seeing the influence of \$V_{GAIN}\$ on the offset voltage, which directly affects the output voltage as well.

Answer (score 1):

I seem to be getting something pretty close to the datasheet:

[image: test]

but I had to probe immediately after the pin for the output (`V(x)`), otherwise there would have been some 18 dB missing (`V(o)`). The input is also a more meaningful 0.1 V (accounted for in the plot window as `*10`). Another thing that's corrected from your schematic is the proper use of an input resistance: you placed it across the voltage source, which is useless, instead of in series. I also didn't use LC filtering since the only noise here is the `double` residuals. The symbol is the generic `[Misc]/DIP8`, for the lack of one, but the pinout is the same. Also, in your waveform window, did you use `log minus log`? The correct way is [`20 * log10( V(out) / V(in) )`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gain_(electronics)#Voltage_gain).